# sencha touch :: adding badgeText to list items

Tags: list, sencha-touch, badge

What would be the best way to add some badgeText to the Items of a List-Panel?

Comment: o.k., so one way to add badge text to a list item is to add the following code to the xtemplate/itemTpl:

 `code`   ...
    '<span class="x-badge">4</span>',
    ...`code`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o.k., so one way to add badge text to a list item is to add the following code to the xtemplate/itemTpl:

```
...
'<span class="x-badge ">4</span>',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch 2.1

```
xtype: 'list',
itemId: 'listMainMenu',
store: 'storeMainMenu',
fullscreen: false,
itemTpl: '<span class="x-badge ">{BadgeText}</span>'
```

and it's not working.

DOM result:

```
<div class="x-innerhtml " id="ext-element-104"><span class="x-badge ">1</span></div>
```

[image: View result]

Comment: And answer is: `itemTpl : '<div class="x-hasbadge"><span class="x-badge ">{BadgeText}</span></div>'`